# UPDATE vs SELECT returns different Execution Plan

Tags: query-performance, optimization, mariadb, explain

In my DB table, where ID is the PK, if I use this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 3;
```

The `type` and the `ref` columns of the explain output table are both equal to `const`.

Now, when I use this:

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE table SET data =xyz WHERE ID = 3;
```

The `type` is `range` and the `ref` is `NULL`. Why is that so? What is the precise meaning of the `ref` column anyway? I really can't find a proper understandable definition online for that column which explains the different value in this example. The `key` column uses the primary key and the `possible_keys` also lists the primary key only in both cases, so I don't understand; I'm using the PK in both cases, but in the `UPDATE` clause less efficiently, although it's basically exactly the same `WHERE` clause?

Comment: can you make a dbfiddle example of the tables so that we can have a [mre]

Comment: This seems "wrong":  `... data FROM table ...`